# Are there any good captchas specifically designed for mobile apps?

Tags: mobile, jquery-mobile, captcha

Is there anything that is less intimidating than recaptcha for mobile apps?  My app is built with JQuery Mobile and most likely will never be available on the desktop.  I am hoping there is a more visual captcha that would not require typing.  So far most visual captchas I have found seem too large for a mobile app.  I am mainly looking for something that is visual and small enough to fit within the average mobile screen.  Any suggestions would be appreciated, I would even be willing to build something from scratch if someone has a good idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if you are using HTML5 or not, but there is a pretty cool captcha that I've used called [MotionCAPTCHA](http://blogupstairs.com/motioncaptcha-%E2%80%93-draw-shapes-captcha-system-for-jquery/). What it does is it presents a shape and the user traces the shape with their finger on their mobile device. Its pretty cool. I've used it with Android and it works pretty well. It requires jQuery and HTML5.

Comment: I like this.  I will probably use this for awhile, but I can see it being cracked sometime in the future if it gets popular enough.  Hopefully with future versions it will add a little more variation.  Going to keep the question open a bit to see if any other solutions come in.

Comment: @Caimen - If you browse the source code for it, you can add your own custom shapes. There is a function called `DollarRecognizer()` in the source code and the shapes are all predefined in there. All you need to do is add your own custom polygon points.

Comment: I'm concerned that the real issue isn't in the number of points, or the complexity of the polygons. I think the problem is that one could write a bot to simulate reading the shape, and then replicating it via an automated mouse cursor or a hacked browser to simply push the necessary values through. This does not seem at all out of reach of a good algorithm. In fact I feel that warped text is much harder to recognize... it would probably be much easier just to replicate the warped text instead of figuring out the meaning behind it.

Comment: [got cut off-->] Basically this is what worries me about this captcha... it relies on replication instead of inference... machines are quite good at replication, but it's the inference part where we humans triumph!

Comment: @Serhiy - True. There is no such thing as 100% secure. In the case of this guy though, I think he's targeting a mobile phone, which in itself, adds an extra layer of security. Being an Android developer, I can almost confidently say that there is no way to create a program that can integrate with the browser and simulate clicks. About the only way to achieve this would be to make your own complete web browser. But I do see your point. We need to make a captcha that uses human inference.

Answer (score 2):

Damn, that MotionCAPTCHA link appears to be dead. I found this question looking for similar things to what we're working on at my current company.

We have a [HumanDetect](https://developer.unify.id/products/humandetect/) mobile SDK trying to solve a similar problem. The overall idea is we grab sensor data from the phone so we can determine "bot or not". You ask the SDK for a token, then send that token along with your REST request, and then that token can be validated. If everything works as expected only a mobile device in the hands of a human should produce a token that validates as "not a bot".

It's native code, not using the browser. For the end-user's point of view, it is transparent, the user isn't asked to perform any action.